# ExpressionEngine 1.6.8 Contact Form

Tags: content-management-system, version, expressionengine, contact-form

I've been asked to make some changes to a site that was built with Expression Engine 1.6.8.  Even though I'm not familiar with this CMS, I can find my way around to make the updates, except I'm not sure about adding a contact form.  I'm guessing that ultimately I'll have to upgrade this version to the newest (2.7, I believe?) in order to get the tags found on this page to work: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/email/contact_form.html?

My only hesitation in making the upgrade is my unfamiliarity with EE, and the fact that someone else is probably creating a brand new website for the one I'm working on, and very likely without EE (so I'm learning something that I may not need again).

Any suggestions for a quick fix, or should I just bite the bullet, upgrade, and use what I've found?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [EE 1.x docs](http://ee1docs.com/modules/email/contact_form.html).

At a glance it appears that syntax has changed little bit.  Maybe that's why your EE2 tags were not working in EE1.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely try to use the tags as shown in the EE1 docs if this site is that old. Making a jump from 1.6.8 to 2.7 can become treacherous due to variables such as how the templates were coded, which add-ons were used, if those add-ons are even available any longer, what functionality was deprecated or absorbed, etc...

I only say ditch the efforts because you mentioned having another site in progress. If you would like to work through the updates/upgrades, follow the docs [here](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/installation/upgrade_from_1.x.html) and [here](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/installation/update.html) and learn it. It is definitely worth the learn. Once you tap into EE, it's hard to roll back.

Comment: These form tags {exp:email:contact_form} {/exp:email:contact_form} are rejected and I think it's because I don't have the email module installed.  That doesn't appear to be available on my list of available modules.  Is that something I can add to what I'm currently working with?  The update process does appear a bit daunting...

Comment: Just to be clear: you are looking for a module called "Email" (not contact form).  I can't remember if it was base install or as a separate purchase.

Comment: It was a free module provided by EL.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing my own html code within the template and processed it with a php script to send the form input to an email address, just as I normally would on a website.  Not being familiar with ExpressionEngine, I don't think I understood why I was continually being referenced to use a module in order to do this, but I suppose for anyone who is not a coder but is experienced with EE, that would be the way to go.  From what I understand, the email module is not free and does not come with the core version, which is what I had to work with, but comes with the licensed version, which made this all the more confusing.